# Android Date Format Convert Eror APP

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(“EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy”); 
Date date= null ;
date = formatter.parse(String.valueOf(m.getSentDate()));
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(“dd.MM.yyyy”);
tarih=formatter.format(date);
```

> ERROR = “java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: “Wed Jan 20 15:13:09 EET 2016″ (at offset 0)”

I get this error code permanently

java mail api from history= Mon jan 18 21:17:31 ETT 2016

I want to convert methods = 18.01.2016 21:17:31
I'm sorry my bad english

Comment: Not sure about your issue.. Can you please explain a bit clearly?

Comment: Why do you post a second input String in your Question? Why does that string have a different time zone code, `EET` vs `ETT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formatter should be working. So something else is wrong.

Here is my example code using your formatter and your input string.

```
String input = "Wed Jan 20 15:13:09 EET 2016";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat ( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" );
Date date = null;
try {
    date = formatter.parse ( input );
} catch ( ParseException e ) {
    System.out.println ( "Exception… " + e );
}

System.out.println ( "date: " + date + " | date via formatter: " + formatter.format ( date ) + " | as Instant: " + date.toInstant () );
```

When run.

> date: Wed Jan 20 05:13:09 PST 2016 | date via formatter: Wed Jan 20 15:13:09 EET 2016 | as Instant: 2016-01-20T13:13:09Z

## Curly-Quotes

I am seeing many curly-quotes in your code and output. Hopefully those are not in the original. Curly quotes are typographically nice but inappropriate in programming code.

If you are using word-processors for your programming, stop that. They are not built for programming and will inject these curly-quotes among many other problems. Learn to use text editors intended for programming source code.

## java.time

By the way, the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. They have been supplanted in Java 8 and later by the new built-in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework.

Comment: It does not work I have a kind of format                                                             I want to convert methods = 18.01.2016 21:17:31

Comment: @MesutDokumacı Your comment and Question are not clear. Try to rewrite them. Say something like "this is my input: x", "this is my code" (stripped-down *minimal* example code that actually runs and is formatted correctly in StackOverflow), "this is what I expected: y", and "this is what I got instead: z". As it is now, I took *your* formatter with *your* data and did not get *your* exception. So I do not understand why you are now talking about some other format. I understand English is not your first language, but that is not really the problem with your Question.

Comment: Mail Server with Java Mail API I get time. Incoming Format = "Mon Jan 20 22:00:12 EST 2016" that I want to change the format from the following new format = "DD.MM.YYYY HH: mm: ss" I want to do it

Comment: @MesutDokumacı You should be editing your Question with further info rather than posting comments. Look for the `edit` link below the tags below your Question, if using a web browser. Also, StackOverflow has thousands of Questions and Answers already posted on the topic of parsing Strings for Dates. Please review those.

Comment: I solved the problem, thank you very much for your help
You are one amazing

Comment: @MesutDokumacı Please post your Answer to explain the solution. May be helpful to others. Also, you can accept your own Answer thereby marking this Question closed/resolved.